What were the Amazons hoping to achieve by sealing the temple?
When the motherbox is awakened in Themyscira, Steppenwolf arrives through a portal to retrieve it. There is big fight inside the temple and in order to save the motherbox, Queen Hippolyta orders her troops to

seal the gates!!.

Given that Steppenwolf arrived through a portal (and also then left through a portal), how did it help to seal the temple off?

It was my understanding that they (the Amazons) had hoped to seal Steppenwolf inside the chamber and then drop it into the sea, killing him. However, I don't know that the Amazons even knew about boom tube technology. The first time they (Steppenwolf) came to Earth it was on spaceships. Boom tube tech may have suprised the Amazons otherwise they would have made a different defense.
